# How to pass argument values to parameters inside of a objects method as a function

Tags: function, object, methods, arguments, parameter-passing

Lets say I have a a object and inside that object I have a function as a property in other words a method, proper JavaScript terminology and with that function I have parameters. How could I pass argument values to that functions parameters would I invoke the argument inside the object or outside the object. Help.

```
 var learningDaily = {                                                                                           
   good: true,
   smarterDaily: true,    
   makingMoney: false,
   needHelp: true
   question: function (question, please) {
               if (question typeOf === Number) { 
                 alert("JUST TELL ME HOW TO PASS ARGUMENTS TO PARAMS IN OBJ");
               } else if (please === "thank you") {
                 alert ("thanks")
               }  else {
                 alert("thank again");  
               }
             },
   getSmarterAfterThis: true
 }
```

Sorry I may have been missing some closing tags bu, pretty much the question is straight forward. Would I invoke the arguments inside the object or outside the object.

```
help(23, "thank you");
```

Comment: Still waiting for answer

Comment: Can somebody answer my question please i have been waiting for a very long time

Comment: my question is pretty striaght foward

Comment: Try to make object more simple. Don't add inside object props that are not used in the example. Write less, be more specific.

Comment: I added a 50 reputation points bounty on your question to help out in,hopefully, getting an answers from someone knowledgeable.

Comment: Call your function using `learningDaily.question(23, "thank you")`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors in your javascript. It's not clear what the method is trying to accomplish. I gather English is not your first language. I'm afraid the question as-written isn't very clear. That's probably why you're having some trouble getting an answer.

Here's an example that ought to get you going in the right direction:

```
obj = {
  value_label: 'The value of x is: ', 
  type_label: '. Its type is ',
  fun: function(x) {
    // Show the value of x with it's type and some label text.
    alert(this.value_label + x + this.type_label + typeof(x) + '.')
  }
};
// Call the method member fun in obj
obj.fun(42)
```

You can paste this into https://jsfiddle.net and run it.